# Cannot convert double? to double

Tags: c#, entity-framework

net and I am trying to verify the value of property is NaN or not 
but it is giving me 'Cannot convert double? to double' this error for below codes, but if I remove '?' in the model all methods works fine 
can you please help on how to verify a double? is NaN or not.

```
public class abcDTO
{
    public double? CondPot { get; set; }
    public double? WaterPot { get; set; }
    public double? WaterInjPot { get; set; }
}
-------

public async Task<abcDTO> UpdateWellDeferment(abcDTO abc)
{
    if (HasValue(abc.CondPot))
        throw new ArgumentException($"CondPot is not a valid number");

        .....       
}
```

---

```
public static bool HasValue(double val)
{
    return Double.IsNaN(val);
}
```

Comment: The ? marks a [nullable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/nullable-types/) type. Try to use the [default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.hasvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) `HasValue()` from nullables or if you definitely want a decimal consider using `.GetValueOrDefault()`

Comment: Don't you rather want to know if the value in the db is `NULL`? So if `abc.CondPot == null`?

Comment: Change it to `HasValue(double? val)` and there check `return val.HasValue && !Double.IsNaN(val.Value)` (i guess that this is the correct logic)

Comment: Convert your if `HasValue()` function to take a `double?` (aka `Nullable<double>`) and then check it's built in `HasValue` property (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1.hasvalue?view=netframework-4.7.2) as well as it's Not-A-Number-ness

Comment: Why do you want to check `IsNaN`? (you would get this by dividing a double zero with zero)

Answer (score 2):

This is only limited automatic conversion from `Nullable<T>` (the actually when you suffix a value type name with `?`) to `T`.

Elsewhere you need to do the conversion, *and decide how to handle `null`*.

Eg. when 0 is a good default:

```
if (HasValue(myNullableDouble ?? 0.0) { ...
```

Other times you need something richer:

```
if (myNullableDouble.HasValue && HasValue(myNullableDouble.Value)) {
  // Has a value
} else {
  // null or NaN
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jaynesh,

When you are using a nullable data type, which is what you are doing when you add the ? operator there. The only thing that can be NaN is Null correct? so you should simply check if the variable has a value. You can do this on a Nullable by calling.

```
abc.CondPot.HasValue
```

and to get the value

```
abc.CondPot.Value
```

Comment: Merci, I fixed it